# Atualizar página defaul ou index .aspx no navegador

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Olá. 
Modifiquei a página default.aspx na hospedagem de meu site mas o navegador continua lendo a default.aspx antiga (que está em seu cache). Provavelmente isso acontecerá nos navegadores de meus clientes.
Digitando o endereço do site (www.meusite.com.br) carrega a página que está no cache, mas se acrescento /default.aspx carrega a página nova, que está no servidor.
Como essa é a primeira página a ser carregada, não sei como forçar sua atualização, seguindo algumas explicações que encontrei aqui no site.
Obrigado.

Comment: Tente apagar o cache do navegador e testar novamente.

Comment: Já fiz isso mas não resolve. Somente informando /default.aspx no final da url. Obrigado.

Comment: Então veja se isso resolva seu problema: http://stackoverflow.com/q/914027/#918346 (eu espero).

Comment: Como a página default.aspx nova não é carregada e sim a que consta no cache do navegador, como que eu poderia chamar as instruções para que a mesma não seja salva no cache do navegador nos próximos acessos? Tem também o problema do navegador dos clientes que já possui a página antiga no cache. Obrigado.

Comment: Err, eu acho melhor tentar trocar de servidor. Você paga o servidor do seu site? Se não, tente migrar para PHP em uma nova hospedagem ou crie um novo site. Se eu soubesse ASP poderia muito ajudar :|